# Delete a node from a binary tree avoiding memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, binary-tree, delete-operator

I want to delete a given node pointer from a binary tree, but I also want to change it with the pointer of one of his children(let's say the left one).

If I do like this:

```
Node<T> *tmp = root->getLeftNode();
delete root;
root = tmp;
```

The pointer root ends up not having the value of the left child.

If I do like this:

```
root = root->getLeftNode();
```

It works, but this is an obvious memory leak.

How can I correctly delete the root?

Edit: I tried my removeNode method using the memory leaks approach and it works (my code seems logically correct). It is just when I use the delete in this way that the root pointer ends up having a large negative number(which is not a valid address).

Comment: What do you mean by "The pointer root ends up not having the value of the left child." ? What is its value then ? Because the assignment is quite clear, I don't see the problem here ...

Comment: The value of the root pointer ends up having a big negative number. Something like -123483978349.

Comment: But if it's a pointer to `struct` or `class`, this is probably juste the pointer value, you have to print the content of the `struct` pointed to by root and NOT `root` itself. Please post your `Node<T>` data structure.

Comment: Be sure not to `delete` your right and left nodes fields in your `Node<T>` destructor.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why my question does not make sense? I was wondering if deleting using this pattern was wrong in the first place. These -1 when I try to write all the correct information in my questions are very annoying. Anyway thank you Unda. I was deleting my left and right node in the destructor.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your answer should be correct, however you need to post a little more information. Are you trying to store the value of the left child in root, or is root a pointer to the node? If you are trying the get the value of the left child, I'd use:

```
root = *tmp;
```